# Do flu shots make sense during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, influenza

My understanding is that the flu shot is a good idea based on a cost benefit analysis. People are likely to get the flu and get sick and the flu shot helps with this. On the other hand, the flu shot costs money and has side effects etc. It appears that the benefits of the flu shot outweigh the costs at a population-based level. However, many people in many countries are engaging in social distancing, don't socialize as much, wash their hands much more, and are always wearing masks around other people due to COVID-19. Presumably this reduces the chances of getting the flu dramatically and therefore the benefits of the flu vaccine may be reduced. For example, perhaps the flue vaccine historically has prevented 50% of recipients from getting the flue, but now most of these people wouldn't get it anyway due to COVID precautions. Note that I just made up this number for illustration.

An acceptable answer will discuss the actual cost benefit analysis. It's very easy to say that it's a good idea to always get a flu shot, but I'm interested in seeing real numbers (even if just approximations!).

Comment: You seem to be asking for this analysis on an individual level rather than a population level, which begs the question of which individuals you had in mind. There are a vast array of differences between people that would completely change the analysis (eg, urban vs. rural, elderly vs. young, immunocompromised vs not... it's a long list). And you ask for real numbers, but where will these numbers come from? As written, I think this question is much too broad.

Comment: @CareyGregory I want the answer to focus on population level knowing what we know about the population's risk with existing COVID precautions. Of course the results change based on the analysis and this applies to every single question out there. What population is used for the flu shot analysis? Let's use the same population (i.e., those eligible for the flu shot?).

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question because of the following sentence: "It appears that the benefits of the flu shot outweigh the costs at a population-based level." That suggests you think the flu shot is justified at the population level, so your question is about the individual level. But if it's about the population level, then you seem to be contradicting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

## Vaccination is more about potential than current burden of disease.

Flu can spread rapidly in an unvaccinated population, and it can be deadly.  The "real" average excess mortality from flu can be a bit controversial and is far enough from the topic that I don't want to dig through sources here, but if you go to the CDC or similar sites you can see some rather striking figures.

Flu *has been* well controlled with masking and social distancing, but if COVID-19 ever truly declines, people will celebrate by abandoning many of these precautions.  I have not seen much about fundamental reforms that would prevent future flu, such as guaranteed state-sponsored sick leave for all employees.

When we look at current vaccination programs - China has vaccinated much more of its population against COVID-19 than most countries, even though it has had extremely few cases.  People are vaccinated against polio in the U.S. even though it is extremely rare.  The alternative for the country would be to await another massive outbreak of respiratory paralysis.  At the individual level it is much less of a stretch to take a flu vaccine now against a virus that is quite likely to have an outbreak in the near future.